# LibGDX: How to do animations on an isometric tiled map?

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, isometric, tiled

I've some problem with LibGDX and tiled maps.
I come from Corona SDK (Lua) and I've used Lime (third party lib to handle tmx maps), now I switched to LibGDX and followed this really recent feature: [`GraphicsTileMaps`](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsTileMaps)

I was able to load an isometric map from assets using `IsometricTiledMapRenderer` as renderer and an `OrthographicCamera` to display the map (all works as described in the wiki page).
I was also able to fill programmatically some tile on the map layer, but my problem starts, when I try to use `AnimatedTiledMapTile`:

```
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load(...);

    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().getLayer("layer1");
    TiledMapTileSet tileset =  map.getTileSets().getTileSet("tileset1");
    TiledMapTile grassTile =  tileset.getTile(4);
    TiledMapTile rockTile =  tileset.getTile(6);

    Array<StaticTiledMapTile> playerTileArr = new Array<StaticTiledMapTile>();
    playerTileArr.add((StaticTiledMapTile)tileset.getTile(7));
    playerTileArr.add((StaticTiledMapTile)tileset.getTile(8));

    Cell grass = new Cell();
    grass.setTile(grassTile);

    Cell player = new Cell();
    player.setTile(new AnimatedTiledMapTile(0.1f, playerTileArr));

    layer.setCell(0,0, grass);  // <--- This works.
    layer.setCell(0,1, player); // <--- When I try this, it causes 
                                //      a NullPointerException.

    renderer = IsometricTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / 30f);
    ...
```

Can someone help?  I found an `AnimatedTiledMapTile` usage example for [`TideMapLoader`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TideMapLoader.java) but I know I'm using a "**tiled** map" (not a "**tide** map"). However.. someone can explain how I can make an animation on a specific tile?

Comment: What problem do you get?

Comment: as in the last 2 rows before "renderer = "
setCell with an animated tile cause a Nullpoint Exception

Comment: try setting (0,0) as the player tile. I think, though not sure, that you're animated part is wrong. This might help http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xubOtuq2cEo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Been by this a few time searching my self.
But got it to work now.

Best guess is that your tileset don't have 7 or 8 tiles.

I got the following code to work:

```
    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0);
    TiledMapTileSet tileset = map.getTileSets().getTileSet(0);

    Array<StaticTiledMapTile> at = new Array<StaticTiledMapTile>();
    if (tileset.getTile(0) != null) at.add((StaticTiledMapTile) tileset.getTile(0));
    if (tileset.getTile(1) != null) at.add((StaticTiledMapTile) tileset.getTile(1));
    if (tileset.getTile(2) != null) at.add((StaticTiledMapTile) tileset.getTile(2));
    if (tileset.getTile(3) != null) at.add((StaticTiledMapTile) tileset.getTile(3));

    layer.getCell(2, 2).setTile(new AnimatedTiledMapTile(0.3f, at));
```

Only getTile(1) and getTile(2) was != null - I only had 2 tiles. (my trouble was that getTile(0) wasnt the first tile.. getTile(1) was!)

Comment: thnks a lot, the problem was in the tileset, tileset.getTile(8) return null after  adding the check you suggested.